# add script to asp.net content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have a google map script that works, but I can't figure out how to add it to my asp.net content page. What is the proper way to add the script to the page?

see code:

```
 <%@ Page Title="Our Location" Language="VB"     MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Frontend.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Location.aspx.vb" Inherits="About_Location" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 

<script type="text/javascript"   
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> 
</script> 

<style type="text/css">  
html { height: 100% }   
body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }  
##map{ height: 100% } 
</style> 

</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMainContent" Runat="Server"    OnLoad="codeAddress()">

<script type= "text/javascript">

var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

function codeAddress() {
    alert("hello")


    //initializes the map

    //create geocoder
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    //set options for the map being created
    var myOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    //create map instance and pass it the myOptions object literal
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    //geocode to get the lat and lng points of the given address
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'New York, New York'}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            //if geocoder finds location
            //center the map on the latlng points of the given address
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setOptions({ zoom: 18 });
            //create marker and place it on the address
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: 'New York, New York'
            });
        }
        else {
            //if geocoder cannot find location, alert user
            alert("Could not find location");
        }
    });




}





</script>

<div id="map" style="width:700px; height:400px;"></div> 

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your script in separate js file, declare it like you did with Google maps script. Then you have to call it, maybe send this "#map" div id as parameter to that script, and not hard code it in javascript.

in this case you want to do that on page load with script manager :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowGoogleMap", "codeAddress('map');", true);
```

btw. for google maps you can use Google Maps server control, it's much easier to use managing maps from server side:

http://googlemap.codeplex.com/